# Displaying YUV420 data using Opengles shader is too slow

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ffmpeg, yuv

I have a child thread called A to decode video using ffmpeg on iPhone 3GS, another thread called B to display yuv data, in thread B, I used glSubTexImage2D to upload Y U V textures, and then convert yuv data to RGB in shader, but the frame rate in the decode thread is only 15fps.Why?

**Update:**
The frame size is 720 * 576.
I also found something interesting that if I didn't start the thread displaying the YUV data, the frame rate calculated in the decode thread is 22 fps,otherwise 15 fps.So I think that my displaying  method must be inefficient.the code as below.

I have a callback in the decode thread:

```
typedef struct _DVDVideoPicture
{
   char *plane[4];
   int iLineSize[4];
}DVDVideoPicture;

void YUVCallBack(void *pYUVData, void *pContext)
{
   VideoView *view = (VideoView *)pContext;
   [view.glView copyYUVData:(DVDVideoPicture *)pData];
   [view calculateFrameRate];
}
```

The copyYUVData method extract the y u v planes separately. The following is displaying thread method.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying that your FFMpeg decode is only happening at 15 FPS, or your upload and processing via your shader is only 15FPS? What size frames are we talking about here? What does your YUV->RGB shader look like?

Comment: In other words, how many frames is FFmpeg decoding per second? This might be a limitation on the ffmpeg side and not your shader.

Comment: @Brad Larson I have update my question, the frame size is 720 *576

Comment: @karlphillip I don't think so.

Comment: IMHO shader dosn't drop FPS. The bottleneck is in decoding. Try to comment calculation of `rgb` in shader, then comment decoding (keep one constant frame) and compare FPS results.

Comment: @brigadir What I mean is that my uploadYV12Texture method cost too much time.